# How to continue testing on OS X 10.7 after moving to 10.8?

Tags: macos, testing, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion

I am wondering how to continue to test on 10.7 when I have upgraded to 10.8.

It seems to me that the obvious solutions are to:
1) virtualise 10.7
2) install it on a separate partition
3) install it on separate hardware.

The problems with each of these are:
1) by the terms of the license, OS X 10.7 cannot be virtualised under 10.8.
2) Second you can no longer buy/download 10.7 to install it on a separate partition.
3) As for 2).

How have people continued to test you software on 10.7 when you are developing under 10.8?  Have you just stopped testing on 10.7?

Thanks
Lee.